# How to fetch dynamic text box value when dynamic check box is checked

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTO4v.png)

Am a fresher in php,want to know how to fetch dynamic text box value when dynamic check box is checked, for example mutton bone is one check box and mutton boneless in one check box (check box comes dynamic) if user checked mutton bone that price will be fetch and display in one text box.want to know how to fetch price value when check box is checked.

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("select distinct type_categ from prod_type");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count > 0) {
    while($row  =mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>

<div>   
<div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="landmark">
     <?php echo $row['type_categ']; ?>
   </label>

 <input type="checkbox"  name="bone[]" id="" class="<?php echo $row['type_categ'].','; ?>Bone" value="<?php echo $row['type_categ'].','; ?>bone" > <?php echo $row['type_categ']; ?>Bone



 <input type="checkbox" name="bone[]" class="<?php echo $row['type_categ'].','; ?>Bone less" value="<?php echo $row['type_categ'].','; ?>boneless"/> <?php echo $row['type_categ']; ?> Bone Less


<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">



    <input  type="text" name="kilo" onblur="calculate()" placeholder="Enter Kg"  class="optional form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 input  <?php echo $result['type_categ'].'c'; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input  type="text" name="price"  onblur="calculate()" placeholder="Amount"  class="optional form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 input <?php echo $result['type_categ'].'d'; ?>">
    <br>
    <br>



    <input id="<?php echo $row['type_categ'].','; ?>Bone" type="text" name="kiloo" onblur="calculate()" class="optional form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 pricek input <?php echo $result['type_categ'].'e'; ?>" readonly>


          <input type="checkbox" name="gravy[]" value="<?php echo $row['type_categ'].','; ?>gravy" >Gravy



<input type="checkbox"  name="gravy[]" value="<?php echo $row['type_categ'].','; ?>chilly"/> Chilly

 <input type="checkbox"  name="gravy[]"  value="<?php echo $row['type_categ'].','; ?>briyani"/> Briyani

</div>
</div>

<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="landmark">Pieces 
   </label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <input type="checkbox" name="pieces[]" value="<?php echo $row['type_categ']; ?>large" >Large
            <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pieces[]" value="<?php echo $row['type_categ']; ?>medium" >Medium
            <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pieces[]" value="<?php echo $row['type_categ']; ?>small">Small

</div>
</div>









</form> 
</div>
    <?php } } ?>   

    <button id="send" type="submit" name="order" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>




<script>
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       var product = $(this).attr("class");
       var arr = product.split(',');
       var pro = $(this).val(); 
     }
    else{
        $(this).val('0');
       var product = $(this).attr("class");
       var arr = product.split(',');
       var pro = $(this).val();    
    }
    $.ajax({
                url:'js/edit_page.php',
                type:'GET',
                data:({product: arr[1] ,pro: pro ,proe: arr[0]}),
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data){

                    $(".pricek").val(data.price);
                    $(".type_categ").val(data.type_categ);
                    $(".type_prod").val(data.type_prod);
                }
            });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: what you have tried so far? use jquery code for that

Comment: @Anant http://needsmorejquery.com/

Comment: why you point me this site? @Gothdo

Comment: i tried this code format. i want to know how can get the price value in the class name price k. value shows but its shows for all text box

Comment: i want to get individual price value for each item while check box is checked